# UI Router: Multiple Independent Views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I feel like this is a straight forward use case for the `ui-router` but maybe I'm missing something...

**I want to have** two separate views next to each other controlled by their own menus.  When I click a `ui-sref` link on one menu (or `$state.go` for that matter), I would like to update only one of the views. Additionally, only one of the two views needs to be reflected in the `url`.

**I tried** defining a few states:

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  views: {
    'viewA': {
      template: "I'm number A!"
    },
    'viewB': {
      template: "It's good to be B."
    }
  }
})
.state('shouldOnlyChangeA', {
  'url': '',
  views: {
    'viewA': {
       template: 'Check out my new shoes!'
     }
  }
})
.state('shouldOnlyChangeB', {
  'url': '/shouldGoToNewUrl',
  views: {
    'viewB': {
       template: "This probably won't work..."
     }
  }
});
```

Now press `$state.go('shouldOnlyChangeA')` from your favorite controller and watch it change the crap out of `viewB`. I'd also like to omit the `url` definition in this state since the `url` should only change between the first and third states I've defined.

I have each `ui-view` sitting next to each other in index.html:

```
...
<div ui-view="viewA"></div>
<div ui-view="viewB"></div>
...
```

### TL;DR

I want two sibling `ui-view`s to be stateful all on their own; changing one shouldn't necessarily effect the other.

Hopefully I'm just missing something so I didn't bother to throw a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) together or anything, but if it's more complicated and folks are willing to fiddle I'll whip something up.

Comment: I think that is not possible with angular-ui-router: It is based on the fact that the URL drives the state and each state corresponds to exactly one combination of views.

You could make state A a child state of the home state (".state('home.shouldOnlyChangeA', {..."), then B would still be alive when you navigate to A, but that is still not really what you asked for.

Comment: This has been my impression as well. I can always use an `ng-include` tied to some `scope` variable for the view that doesn't require `url` updates, but since it really is a view with multiple states I was hoping there was a way.

Comment: Yup, seems that way: I just found a roadmap https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Roadmap
where one two bullet points say
* support for independent "components" (re-usable state tree branches) with their own states that can be instantiated multiple times in the global (or a parent component) state hierarchy (See #123 and See #95)
* Orthogonal view routing. Two views who have sub-trees of their own, who's states are automatically serialized to the url. Strongly related to "components" idea above.

Found this in a discussion about future angularjs 2.0 routing.

Comment: @StephenFriedrich FYI you can use UI-Router Extras for this. See answer.

Comment: Great! Wish I had known about UI-Router Extras earlier - now it's too late to restructure my gui to take advantage of it. Oh well, probably for the next project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See this similar question: [Independent routing for multiple regions in an AngularJS single page application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065137)

---

I wrote [UI-Router Extras](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/home) - [sticky states](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky) to accomplish this use case.

View the [demo](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/sticky/index.html#/) 
Check out the [demo source code](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/tree/gh-pages/example/sticky) for details.

I wrote [UI-Router Extras](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/home) - [sticky states](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky) to achieve your goal.

You'll want one named `<div ui-view='name'></div>` for each region.  Then, add `sticky: true` to the state definition which targets that region's named view.

See this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/nc5ebdDonDfxc1PjwEHp?p=preview

```
<div ui-view="viewA"></div>
<div ui-view="viewB"></div>
```

...

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: '/'
 })
.state('shouldOnlyChangeA', {
  'url': '',
  sticky: true, // Root of independent state tree marked 'sticky'
  views: {
    'viewA@': {
       template: 'Check out my new shoes!<div ui-view></div>'
     }
  }
})
.state('shouldOnlyChangeA.substate', {
  'url': '/substate',
  template: 'Lets get some shoes!'
})
.state('shouldOnlyChangeB', {
  'url': '/shouldGoToNewUrl',
  sticky: true,  // Root of independent state tree marked 'sticky'
  views: {
    'viewB': {
       template: "This probably won't work...<div ui-view></div>"
     }
  }
})
.state('shouldOnlyChangeB.substate', {
  'url': '/substate',
  template: "Golly, it worked"
  }
);
```