# Is it possible to have multiple states on a page at once or change the state of a named view?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am developing a page that has a news feed on it; when I think of it logically, this feed has several states on it (news, settings, favorites, etc.).

A feed should be able to be on many types of pages, such as for a product or a person or whatnot, so the way I understand it is that the feed itself should have states because their parent page can have all sorts of other states that the feed does not care about, and vice versa.

I can't figure out how to accomplish this -- at first I thought that I would be able to accomplish this using a named view on the parent page but can't figure out if a view can have a state, or how I would code that.

How should I be implementing this structure?

Comment: Please see my previous answers utilizing UI-Router Extras "Sticky States".   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065137/independent-routing-for-multiple-regions-in-an-angularjs-single-page-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114394/ui-router-multiple-independent-views/26126797#26126797

Comment: Wow, that's some impressive stuff and I think that's what I'm looking to do! Looking into it more soon.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for sounds a lot like a directive:

- A directive usually has an HTML template associated to it
- A directive backs this HTML template with a scope that can (and usually should) be independent of the page scope, with only a few explicitly defined parameters (values and/or functions) passed to it
- A directive can define specific behaviours and functions, just as a regular page would via its controller
- A directive can nonetheless communicate with its parent page, whether because it shares its scope (usually a bad idea) or because there is two-way binding of select fields
- Optionally a directive can communicate with other directives (in your application, this could be useful if you define a "rss feed" directive and a "rss news item" for example)

The states would be variables, some of which you pass to your directive from your page, some you compute inside the directive. They would in turn parameterize the directive HTML template with the usual angular behaviours (e.g. ng-hide/show some subcomponents).

Angular directive doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
A good tutorial : http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/

Does that answer your question ?

Comment: The only reason I don't really believe this would be a directive is because there appears to be no way to involve the concept of states with a directive. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Can you expand on what states are for you, that well-defined variables and adaptive view components can't cover ?