# How can I make the first and second views simultaneously visible?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need two `views` which will be showed independently of each other. But when I click on the one the other being removed. I need not a child `state` but like a siblings. It is even possible?

Please, help. This is my [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iPW6MqtEmDuMFRCFSX3V?p=preview)

```
<body ng-app="SiblingViews">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div>
      <a ui-sref="view1">View_1</a>
      <a ui-sref="view2">View_2</a>
    </div>
    <div ui-view="first"></div>
    <div ui-view="second"></div>
</body>
```

```
$stateProvider
        .state('view1', {
            url: '/view-1',
            views: {
                'first': {
                    templateUrl: 'first.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('view2', {
            url: '/view-2',
            views: {
                'second': {
                    templateUrl: 'second.html'
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065137/independent-routing-for-multiple-regions-in-an-angularjs-single-page-application) can help;

Comment: Close enough, but not exactly. Any way thanks, @user3335966!

Comment: You can only have one active state, but each state can have multiple view.